# SIGSEGV exception in my iOS app crash report

Tags: ios, objective-c, crash, crash-reports

I keep receiving this crash report and I can't figure out where the problem is.
I understand that SIGSEGV exception type is usually due to a memory management issue.

According to line 9, the crash occurs when function `cxx_destruct` is called inside the SoundsViewController, is it right? I see in my code that line 182 in this controller is the end of the `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` function.

Does it mean that there're some variables that are not released properly? How do I find them? I enabled Zombie, which helped me to fix another crash but nothing about this one.

I'll appreciate any help. Thank you!

```
Exception Type:  SIGSEGV
Exception Codes: SEGV_ACCERR at 0xe15e7790
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x38656b26 +[Protocol load] + 1289
1   Foundation                          0x2ec6803b -[NSThread description] + 1710
2   CoreFoundation                      0x2e25018b -[__NSCFLocale initWithLocaleIdentifier:] + 20334
3   CoreFoundation                      0x2e24f65b -[__NSCFLocale initWithLocaleIdentifier:] + 17470
4   CoreFoundation                      0x2e24de4f -[__NSCFLocale initWithLocaleIdentifier:] + 11314
5   CoreFoundation                      0x2e1b8ce7 0x2e1b1000 + 31975
6   CoreFoundation                      0x2e1b8acb 0x2e1b1000 + 31435
7   GraphicsServices                    0x32ed9283 -[_UIFontExtraData dealloc] + 25990
8   UIKit                               0x30a5aa41 -[UIScrollView _addContentSubview:atBack:] + 1492
9   MyApp1.2.0                          0x0004325f -[SoundsViewController .cxx_destruct] + 182
```

Answer (score 1):

You can refer this link 
http://kevincupp.com/2011/05/12/symbolicating-ios-crash-logs.html
This problem is because of deallocation of SoundsViewController.
Check retain values of SoundsViewController.

Answer (score 1):

Turn on Zombie detection in Instruments. This looks on the face of it like a dangling delegate (i.e. some object is trying to invoke a delegate reference, but the delegate target has been unloaded from memory). You could use some instrumentation to track it down.

Comment: Thank you Echelon. It was indeed a dangling delegate. I used this great tutorial to learn about the memory management [http://www.raywenderlich.com/5677/beginning-arc-in-ios-5-part-1](http://www.raywenderlich.com/5677/beginning-arc-in-ios-5-part-1)